# Primary key is missing even though it does exist

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Strange issue I have a primary key on a table but when I compile and run my program entity brakes and complains that it does not exist.

[image]

This is the error I am getting:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   WindowsFormsApplication1.Coverage: EntityType 'Coverage' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   Coverages: EntityType: EntitySet 'Coverages' is based on type 'Coverage' that has no keys defined

Even though it is defined in my SQL Server database as the primary key and is an identity column.

[image]

Now I am switching to my database through Code and I am wondering is that part of my problem.

```
public string SetupConnections()
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

    try
    {
        // Specify the provider name, server and database.
        string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        string serverName = "sourcenet";
        string databaseName = "COASTALCAROLINAPODIATRY";

        // Initialize the connection string builder for the underlying provider.
        // Set the properties for the data source.
        sqlBuilder.DataSource = serverName;
        sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
        sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        // sqlBuilder.UserID = "scheduler";
        // sqlBuilder.Password = "Y=1.5x+10";

        // Build the connection string.
        string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

        // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

        // Set the provider name.
        entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;

        // Set the provider-specific connection string.
        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

        // Set the Metadata location.
        entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl";

        Console.WriteLine(entityBuilder.ToString());

        using (EntityConnection conn = new EntityConnection(entityBuilder.ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Just testing the connection.");
            conn.Close();
        }
}
```

Then in my model I have the following

```
public SMBASchedulerEntities() : base("name=SMBASchedulerEntities")
{
}

public SMBASchedulerEntities(string connectionstring) : base(connectionstring)
{
}

public virtual DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<AppointmentType> AppointmentTypes { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Carrier> Carriers { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<NextID> NextIDs { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Option> Options { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Policy> Policies { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Provider> Providers { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Referral> Referrals { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Coverage> Coverages { get; set; }
```

**Edit 2**

Ok so as a test I removed the connection string object and placed it here instead like this and works wonder what is wrong.

This works passing connection string does not?

```
public SMBASchedulerEntities(string connectionstring) : base("name=SMBASchedulerEntities")
{
}
```

**Edit 3**

This is what the connection builder creates:

```
Data Source=sourcenet;Initial Catalog=COASTALCAROLINAPODIATRY;Integrated Security=True
```

Code:

```
public SMBASchedulerEntities(string connectionstring) : base(connectionstring)
{
}
```

Which does not work when passed through to above method I am sure someone out there has done this.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the error.  It isn't saying your table doesn't have a primary key.  It's saying your EF model has no key defined.

Comment: @Amy I am using DB first generating my model from the db so shouldnt this happen auomatic what is the solution.

Comment: have you tried refreshing your EF EDMX model?

Comment: Can you post the CSDL part corresponding to the definition of the Coverage entity?

Comment: yes I have  refreshed it etc and its not connecting it where would i find that @mnieto

Comment: it's in your edmx file. Open it with a xml editor

Comment: In the first screenshot you showed click on the `CoverageId` column to select it and change the `Entity Key` property to `true`.

Comment: @Equalsk it is already set as a property of type k

Comment: What happens if you correct the spelling from `ConverageId` to `CoverageId`?

Comment: @DStanley should that even matter shouldnt the genration be finiding it if its a pimary key

Comment: Please see edit 3 guys and girls may give a more better explaniation of what is hapening

Comment: @davidbuc EF will "auto-assign" a primary key based on some rules, one of which is the presence of a {entity name} + "Id" field, so it might. Plus, it was bugging me :)

Comment: I change it to id and appeared to work but its still down to my issue in edit 3 its really buggin me this should be simple

Comment: I think you have a couple of issues here, and to better troubleshoot them, they need to be broken into parts, and you need to ask a question for each.

The original issue is EF not associating the correct primary key to the Coverage table. It seems as though that's been solved in the comments. Someone should write that up as an answer, and then close this question as answered.

The new issue appears to be confusion over how the connection string works and having some other connectivity issues. That is a totally separate issue from a primary key issue, and needs it's own question.

Comment: ORMs are weird. An earlier comment noted that there are some heuristics that EF uses to find the PK for a table. In this case, I think the typo in your screenshot (`ConverageId` vs the table name of `Coverage`) is contributing to EF not finding the PK.